# Match text for highlight js formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match some message string to use as a formatted "codeblock" with highlight js. Here's the code that I'm using now:

```
var regex = /\`\`\`([^*]+)\n([^*]+)\`\`\`/g;
msg = msg.replace(regex, `<pre><code class="scrollbarGhost-2F9Zj2 scrollbar-3dvm_9 hljs $1" style="position: relative;">$2</code></pre>`);
```

And here's some example msg text:

````
```js
function smth(){
    return "hi"
}```
````

````
```cs
Console.WriteLine("etc");
```
````

````
```php
function smth($s){
    return $s;
}```
````

I'm trying to take the js part and put it in the slot for $1, and then the rest of the text afterwards in slot $2. Right now, its putting 
`js
function smth(){
    return "hi"`
in slot $1, and `}` in slot $2.
How do I fix this and only detect js for $1?

Comment: @wp78de no, its dynamic so if it were cs i would want cs to be in $1 slot

Comment: You did not mention that. You should always give a sufficient number of samples.

Comment: added more examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from your *updated* description, you are looking for regex like this:

```
\`\`\`(\w+)\n((?:(?!\`\`\`)[\s\S])*)\`\`\`
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfEIHL/4)

It returns the output as desired.

Answer (score -1):

Regex:

```
\`\`\`(.*)\n([^}]*})\`\`\`
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/warPEI/3)

Comment: it wont always end with }, its dynamic string

Answer (score -1):

After the update in the answer, you would have to use the negative lookahead along with the non-capturing group. It works with all the updated examples.

```
\`\`\`(.*)\n((?:(?!\`\`\`)(.|[\r\n]))+)\`\`\`
```

[image]

Comment: The string is dynamic, whats after js will be different types of code and string.